# Algorithm that will identify valid IPv4 addresses

Tags: c#, ip

I have to write an algorithm that will identify valid IPv4 addresses in dot-decimal format. IPs should be considered valid if they consist of four octets, with values between 0..255 (included) also zeros (e.g. 01.02.03.04) are considered not valid.

```
public static bool is_valid_IP(string IpAddres)
{
    string[] adress = IpAddres.Split('.');

    if (adress.Length!=4)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int result;
        if (adress[i][0]=='0')
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!int.TryParse(adress[i], out result))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (result >255)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    return true;
}
```

It does work with all the IP I did try but the tests in my school (have not idea what they are) are saying that it's wrong. Can someone point what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your question needs to include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, as well as _specific_ information about what the code does and what you want instead. The MCVE will necessarily include examples of the inputs that produce incorrect results, as well as an explanation as to what is not correct about the results. With the question as it is now, all you're going to get, instead of good, useful answers, are random guesses (see below) as to what specific criteria your algorithm may or may not be successfully implementing.

Comment: What happens if you pass in `a..b.c` as the input?

Answer (score 2):

[`0.0.0.0` is a valid IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) whereas [the following will reject it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rVugzE).

```
if (adress[i][0]=='0')
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the IPAddress class to parse it?

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should make a note that this will do Ipv6 as well and may not be what the OP is looking for . from msdn "**A string that contains an IP address in dotted-quad notation for IPv4 and in colon-hexadecimal notation for IPv6.**"

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your parser would say double or single digit negative ips are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check for leading zeros, if it exists return false, your test only check for the first 0, if the test was 001.002.003.4, it will fail, use 
`if (adress.StartsWith("0"))` but exclude 0.0.0.0

you will also need to check for negative numbers, use your result from TryParse